# extracting residual series for every element in a list

Tags: r

I run 1000 linear regressions simultaneously and get results in form of lists of list. Now I want to extract residual series from every regression and make a data set combining residuals for every regression.I have run following codes and get residuals. Please help me to combine residuals from different models.

```
set.seed(1234)
library(xts)
library(zoo)
set.seed(1234)
ys<-data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000),nrow=100))
x<-data.frame(matrix(rnorm(200),nrow = 100))
date<-as.Date("2010-01-01")+0:99
colnames(x)<-c("ts","cs")
ys<-xts(ys,order.by = date)
x<-xts(x,order.by = date)
models<-apply(ys,2,function(y) {lm(y~x)})
models_residuals<-lapply(models,function(x) {x[2]})
```

Comment: I think you already get each models' residual. What does `combine residuals mean from different models` mean?

Comment: @Travis Sir I got models_residuals. I want to make data frame of these residuals by combining all residuals. I mean cbind of all residuals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Method1:

The idea is that `data.frame` can take list input and will treat each elements of list as a col. There may be some restrictions on the input, like elements should be equal length etc. Also, this method will generate a messy column names.

For example:

```
data.frame(list(list(1:2),list(2:3)))
```

> **Output:**
>
> ```
>   X1.2 X2.3
> 1    1    2
> 2    2    3
> ```

**Code:**

```
# each sub list will be a column
res_df <-  data.frame(models_residuals)
# rename the dataframe 
names(res_df) <- paste(names(ys),'res',sep='_')

head(res_df)
```

**Output:**

[image]

#### Method 2:

Since each element of your list is also a list, this method will `unlist` each sub elements in your list and then convert it to a vector.

```
res_df = lapply(models_residuals,function(x){as.vector(unlist(x))})
res_df = data.frame(res_df)
head(res_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

`lm` allows a matrix of dependent variables so this would work to regress each column of `ys` on `x` and get the residuals:

```
resid(lm(ys ~ x)))
```